# I need to extract the panel of my JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I need to know which method gives you the panel `panelA` from my `scrollpane`.
For example, I have:

```
PanelExample panelA = new PanelExample();
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(panelA,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrollpane.getPanel();  //???
scrollpane.getComponent();  //???
```

I guess it should be a `get` method, but I don't know.

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the component from the `JViewport` of the `JScrollPane`:

```
Component c = scrollPane.getViewport().getView();
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for information on how the scroll pane works and the components involved in the layout of the scroll pane.